# How to catch specific Exception in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, service

VB.NET 2010, Framework 3.5

Not just Catch the Exception but also identify exactly what type of error it is. To create the error write to the PC's Event Log when the Event Log is full.  The sample below throws a System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception. That's great and all but it doesn't tell me that the 'Event Log is full', it could be other errors the are encompassed by System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception.  Is it safe to look at ErrorCode = -2147467259 or NativeErrorCode = 1502 to determine that the Event Log is full?

```
Sub Main()
    Try

        Do While True ' this loop will overflow the Event Log
            EventLog.WriteEntry("source", "message")
        Loop

    Catch w As System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
        If w.ErrorCode = -2147467259 Then
            ' will ErrorCode always = -2147467259 when The Event Log file is full?
        End If
        If w.NativeErrorCode = 1502 Then
            ' will NativeErrorCode always = 1502 when The Event Log file is full?
        End If
        If w.Message = "The event log file is full" Then
            ' code for event log is full
        End If

        If w.ErrorCode = -2147467259 Then
            If w.NativeErrorCode = 1502 Then
                If w.Message = "The event log file is full" Then
                    ' code for event log is full if all 3 conditions are True? 
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It may be possible to get more information from the innerException property.

Comment: Just make sure `InnerException` isn't `Nothing`, or you now have another exception :)